# Burn Bootstrapper - Preventing Modify/Uninstall page from appearing after installation

Tags: cisco, burn, wix4

## **Issue:**

I am attempting to install a [Cisco AnyConnect](https://software.cisco.com/download/home/286281283/type/282364313/release/4.10.08025) pre-deployment package utilizing the [Burn bootstrapper](https://wixtoolset.org/docs/tools/burn/) and [Wix V4](https://wixtoolset.org/docs/about/). However, when I attempt to install the package, the bootstrapper automatically launches the 'Modify/Uninstall' page after completing the installation.

## **Demonstration:**

To demonstrate this issue, I have created an out-of-the-box burn bundle solution and am attempting to install the Cisco AnyConnect package using the link above:

```
<Wix xmlns="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs" 
     xmlns:bal="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs/bal">
  <Bundle Name="Bundle1" Manufacturer="TODO Manufacturer" Version="1.0.0.0" UpgradeCode="57aeb355-8a20-45b2-8fc5-0b79be7211d1">
    <BootstrapperApplication>
      <bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication LicenseUrl="https://www.example.com/license" Theme="hyperlinkLicense" />
    </BootstrapperApplication>

    <Chain>
      <MsiPackage SourceFile="C:\temp\Cisco\anyconnect-win-4.10.07073-core-vpn-predeploy-k9.msi" Visible="yes" />
    </Chain>
  </Bundle>
</Wix>
```

When running the bootstrapper I get the following sequence of pages:

[Bundle Sequence of Pages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7Na3.png)

The 'Modify/Uninstall' page seems to appear a second after the 'Success' page is loaded and both pages stay open until closed.

There are four temporary log files being generated each time the bundle is executed. The logfiles can be found [here](https://github.com/orgs/wixtoolset/discussions/7980).

## **Expectation:**

My desired behavior is for the 'Modify/Uninstall' page to not be displayed when the installation is complete. Having the 'Modify/Uninstall' page display immediately after the installation is complete creates a confusing user experience.